# Is it possible to edit list views or add xslt without SharePoint Designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt-list-view-web-part, visual-studio-2013, aspx, list-view-web-part

Is it possible to edit list views or add xslt without SharePoint Designer?

SP Designer is blocked, but I have visual studio. I noticed I can see the "*advanced edit*" portions of the AllItems page, but cannot edit the fields or any content of the list by opening the page in Visual Studio or Dreamweaver.

Is this possible without SPD?

[image: Designer View]

[image: Visual Studio View]

Comment: Explain Dilbert's **manager** you are not allowed to use a pocket-knife but are allowed to use a chain-saw. It is his choice which one you use on his precious SharePoint environment.